# Correct way to read elf files in C

Tags: c, linux, elf

I'm trying to follow this guide: http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial to process `elf files`.

However, function `bool elf_check_fil` states, that given file is not a correct elf (despite `readelf` showing that it is)

**Code:**

```
bool elf_check_file(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr) {
    if(!hdr) return false;
    if(hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG0] != ELFMAG0) {
        ERROR("ELF Header EI_MAG0 incorrect.\n");
        return false;
    }
    if(hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG1] != ELFMAG1) {
        ERROR("ELF Header EI_MAG1 incorrect.\n");
        return false;
    }
    if(hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG2] != ELFMAG2) {
        ERROR("ELF Header EI_MAG2 incorrect.\n");
        return false;
    }
    if(hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG3] != ELFMAG3) {
        ERROR("ELF Header EI_MAG3 incorrect.\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Loading the file:**

```
FILE* elf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
Elf32_Ehdr *hdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *) elf;
elf_check_file(hdr);
```

Using `gdb` I checked that `hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG0]`...`hdr->e_ident[EI_MAG3]` in fact do not contain correct magic numbers. Why?

Comment: `elf_check_file` expects contents of elf file, not filehandle. You can't just cast `FILE *` to `Elf32_Ehdr *`, you have to read the contents.

Comment: There also a problem that you open the file as a *text* file.

Comment: You need 'rb'.  Elves are binaries.  Trolls and vamps, you can open as text, but not elves.

Comment: So I should first use `fread` on the `FILE *`? And before that find size of the elf using `fseek`?

Comment: All you need to read is the file header, that will give you enough information to parse the rest of the file. You don't need to know the size of the file beforehand.

Comment: If you think you need a cast, somebody somewhere is probably doing something wrong, and chances are it's you (not always obviously). Check the documentation. If it says you need a cast, go for it. Otherwise stop and think again.

Comment: @MrM. "So I should first use `fread` on the `FILE *`?"  Yes.  Or `open()` and `read()`. You might even `mmap()` the entire file and access it that way. "And before that find size of the elf using `fseek`?" That's not guaranteed to work. It works on Linux, but if you read the C Standard on `fseek()` and `ftell()`, you'll find that standard clearly states that won't give you the size of a file opened in text mode, and also that binary files aren't guaranteed to be seekable to the end of the file. Since `fseek()` to the end only works under POSIX, use POSIX `stat()` or `fstat()` to get the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by multiple comments, you are not using `elf_check_file` correctly.

Correct way should be something like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if (fp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s': %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
  return;
}

Elf32_Ehdr ehdr;
if (fread(&ehdr, sizeof(ehdr), 1, fp) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "fread: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  fclose(fp);
  return;
}

if (!elf_check_file(&ehdr)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "'%s' is not an ELF file\n", argv[1]);
  fclose(fp);
  return;
}
/* Parse the rest of the ELF file here. */

/* Don't forget to close the file. */
fclose(fp);
return;
```